# Can't send GET to HTTPS service with cert, error: certificate verify failed: self signed certificate

Tags: python, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm trying to send a **GET request** to a host with (supposedly) correct certificates.

It's a university task, and they gave me these certificates. (which are only valid for 30 seconds)

But the code below gives me the error that `certificate verify failed: self signed certificate`

The package I got from the host in response says that **Fatal Error: Unknown CA.**

What could cause the issue? Thanks!

```
   context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
   context.load_cert_chain('clientcert.pem', keyfile='clientkey.pem')
   connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection(IP)
   connection.request("GET", "/")
   response = connection.getresponse()
   print("response:", response)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be self-explanatory. Self-signed SSL certificates always cause security warnings/errors. You will either need to add your self-signed SSL as an exception or add the self-signed CA to OS trusted certificates pool.

You may also try using something identical to `--insecure` option in `curl`.